# how to excecute a command in command prompt using python

Tags: python-3.x

ANGULAR_PROJECT_PATH  = "C:\Users\admuser3\Desktop\Angular demo\angular-flask"

I want to execute a command in the command prompt in windows this is my command :

```
" ng build --watch --base-href /static/ "
```

and I want to run this command in this ANGULAR_PROJECT_PATH

here the condition is:

for every 10 seconds, I have to run this command automatically

In Linux, I saw this command but I don't know how to do it in windows:

```
 subprocess.call(('cd ' + ANGULAR_PROJECT_PATH + ' && ng build --watch --base-href /static/ &'), shell=True)
```

Comment: I can't imagine a situation that requires to build an Angular application every 10 seconds (so why you use the --watch parameter?). Try to use a single "&"  (instead of "&&") to separate the commands ("cd ..." and "ng build ..."). It execute the second command if the first one is successful.